# Defining the set for which a function that is one-to-one is also onto

Tags: real-analysis, functions

My question is part of an overall larger question which requires me to take the given one-to-one function $f: A \rightarrow B$, and make it onto as well. I know when I do that, the resulting codomain, $C$ must be a subset of $B$. I'm having trouble defining the set $C$ in a succinct way.

I know that for a function $f: A \rightarrow C$  to be onto, for all $c \in C$, there must exist some $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = c$. I also know that each $c \in C$ must also be in $B$.

This has been my best attempt so far: $C = {\{c \in B: f(A)=c\}}$

Does this capture what I'm trying to say?

Comment: What is $f(A)$?

Comment: It's $f(a)$ $\forall a \in A$.

Comment: ... which looks an awful lot like your $C$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring ah, so would it just be f(A) = C? The condition for c to be an element of B isn't necessary. If $f(A) = C$ then $C \subset B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C$ is the set of the images of all the elements of $ A $.

$$C=f(A)$$
$$=\{ f(x), x\in A\}$$

$$=\{y\in B \; : \;\Bigl( (\exists x\in A)\;:\; f(x)=y\Bigr)\}$$

$f : A \to C $ is onto.